# Python web.py peewee and heroku

Tags: python, heroku, peewee

I have a small all based on web.py and peewee. Deployment to heroku goes fine and I have a DB running, but how do I configure peewee to use the heroku postgress db?

The peewee documentation doesn't reveal anything useful http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#PostgresqlDatabase

I have tried

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase('database', user='user', password='password', host='host')
```

Forgot the log snippet from "heroku logs"

```
2013-04-15T17:11:21.093479+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1639, in connect
2013-04-15T17:11:21.093255+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myapp.py", line 5, in <module>
2013-04-15T17:11:21.093479+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__local.conn = self._connect(self.database, **self.connect_kwargs)
```

*Update*
I tried to change the postgresql settings to

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")
```

now I am getting

```
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345227+00:00 app[web.1]:     db.connect()
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1639, in connect
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345227+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__local.conn = self._connect(self.database, **self.connect_kwargs)
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1810, in _connect
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]:     return psycopg2.connect(database=database, **kwargs)
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]:     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]:    Is the server running locally and accepting
2013-04-16T19:11:02.345582+00:00 app[web.1]:    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? I.e. what error message did you get?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html, after several hours of googling and testing, the correct way to connect is

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase(
    database='',
    user='',
    password='',
    host='',
    port='5432'
  )
```

this lets peewee connect to postgresql on Heroku

Answer (score -1):

If you do not know your database's configuration when the interpreter starts up, you can "defer" initializaiton and set the database connection parameters at run-time:

http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html#deferring-initialization